# How to remove casting enum types in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

how can I remove casting to int for enum types in sql generator?

WHERE (1 =  CAST( [Extent1].[MyEnumType] AS int))

I need to have just

WHERE (1 =  MyEnumType)

I tried to add [Column[TypeName="int"]] to property but without effect.

Comment: yes, it is code first

Comment: Could you share the code that produced this SQL as well as the property definition that's mapped to this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in Entity Framework 6.1.2. Please see https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/186. I was able to verify that the upgrade from 6.1.1 to 6.1.3 fixed this very problem for us.